# Symfony 2 Logging exceptions in console

Tags: php, logging, symfony, console-application, error-logging

Why errors from console tasks are not logged.
For example Exception on php warning:

`[ErrorException]

  Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/project/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php line 298`

I see what printed in stdout, but nothing logged to logs. (I use console commands in cron).
In web these exceptions logged with backtrace, which in this situation is more informational than just this exception.

As a solution: I enclose all process function in try..catch block and log the backtrace manually.

Is anyone know how to enable or configure logging in console tasks.
I think it must be somewhere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I followed the code, there's actually no such an option to enable logging for commands. In `app/console` is this code:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;

...

$application = new Application($kernel);
$application->run();
```

It calls `Symfony\Component\Console\Application::run()` in which there's try/catch block. On exception method `renderException()` is called, but no logging happens anywhere.

Also note that `app/console` always by default exits with error code on exception.

You can create you own `Application` class extending `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application` and modify `app/console` to use it. Than you can override `run()` method and add errors logging.

Or you can modify just `app/console` and handle erros like this:

```
// $application->run();
$application->setCatchExceptions(false);
try {
    $output = new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput();
    $application->run(null, $output);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    ... error logging ...

    $application->renderException($e, $output);

    $statusCode = $e->getCode();
    $statusCode = is_numeric($statusCode) && $statusCode ? $statusCode : 1;
    exit($statusCode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I dig into launch files console & index.php but should dig deeper  in Application class.

But it seems that application classes in web & console share the same behavior.

Comment: yay for `setCatchExceptions`. this example could be improved by `Throwable` instead of `Exception` on newer php versions. :)

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR** : just use [this bundle](https://github.com/OpaleNet/ConsoleExceptionBundle)

From the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/logging.html#enabling-automatic-exceptions-logging) :

> To get your console application to automatically log uncaught exceptions for all of your commands, you can use console events.

Create a service tagged as an event listener for the `console.exception` event :

```
# services.yml
services:
    kernel.listener.command_dispatch:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ConsoleExceptionListener
    arguments:
        logger: "@logger"
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: console.exception }
```

You can now do whatever you want with console exceptions :

```
<?php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/EventListener/ConsoleExceptionListener.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleExceptionEvent;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class ConsoleExceptionListener
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function onConsoleException(ConsoleExceptionEvent $event)
    {
    $command = $event->getCommand();
    $exception = $event->getException();

    $message = sprintf(
        '%s: %s (uncaught exception) at %s line %s while running console command `%s`',
        get_class($exception),
        $exception->getMessage(),
        $exception->getFile(),
        $exception->getLine(),
        $command->getName()
    );

    $this->logger->error($message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, since Symfony 2.3 this is a better solution.

Answer (score 6):

If that's the matter of simply understanding what went wrong where, you can run your app with the verbose flag `-v` or `--verbose`, which will [automatically print the exception trace](https://github.com/symfony/Console/blob/3741aee1418a64e5207f273cf85072a3b673a432/Application.php#L705-L729) on the screen.

[image]

Comment: You are right, but question was about writing errors to log (for ex. in file)

It was necessary when i run cli commands from cron

Comment: True, sorry, missed the cron part. Couldn't figure out how get to the backtrace without complicating it all too much, decided to share the findings.

Comment: @IanBytchek, thank you anyway, your answer helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to implement your own custom `OutputInterface` class and  override the `writeln` method to log the error there. Then use the new class when you execute the `run()` method.

This way you can adhere to the [Open/Close Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) of Symfony without having to modify the base classes and still achieve your goals.